# Error "Missing implementation of resolved method of abstract class " when trying to use covariant returned type

Tags: java, signature, covariant-return-types

I have an abstract class with one abstract method:

```
class A {
    public abstract Element getA();
}
```

I have several classes that have already implemented this abstract class, and they work fine. For some reasons, I cannot change the method signature of these classes.

```
class A1 extends A {
    @Override
    public Element getA() {
        // Implementation in A1
    }
}
```

Now, I'm creating a new class, A2, which extends the abstract class A. However, instead of returning an Element object, I want it to return a list of Element objects.

```
class A2 extends A {
    @Override
    public List<Element> getA() {
        // Implementation in A2
    }
}
```

To change the return type of the subclass, I thought about using covariant return types. So, I changed the return type of the abstract class to Object:

```
class A {
    public abstract Object getA();
}
```

It compiles without errors and I have no errors when calling A2.getA() but I encounter a runtime error when calling A1.getA(): ""Missing implementation of resolved method 'abstract java.lang.Object getA()' of abstract class A.""

Any advice on how to resolve this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have forgotten to *recompile* `A1`, after you changed `A`.

There is no return type covariance in the JVM. The JVM doesn't consider `Element getA()` to implement `Object getA()`. The Java compiler achieves return type covariance by generating an additional bridge method, with the correct return type.

So after you changed `A.getA()` to return `Object`, `A2` is compiled to something like this:

```
class A2 extends A {
    public List<Element> getA() {
        // Implementation in A2
    }

    // This is not valid Java code
    // This is just to illustrate that the compiler generates this additional method in the bytecode
    @Override
    public Object getA() {
        return getA() // this will call the getA that returns List<Element>
    }
}
```

As far as the JVM is concerned, the `Object`-returning `getA` is what implements the abstract method. If you only have the `List<Element>`-returning `getA`, the JVM thinks that the abstract method is unimplemented.

Let's see what happens if you forgot to recompile `A1`. The bytecode for `A1` would only contain an `Element`-returning `getA`, because when you first compiled `A1`, the return type matched the abstract method's return type - there was no need to generate a bridge method. But now you changed the abstract method's return type, so the existing `getA` method in `A1` doesn't implement the abstract method anymore!

You should recompile `A1` so that a bridge method is generated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already recompiled several times with mvn -U clean install for the entire project.

Comment: @Arevik Well I'm afraid you need to give more debugging details.